# Corrupt Excel File when saving with OleContainer

Tags: c++, ole

Using CPP Builder XE7. Saving an Excel-file with an OleContainer produces a corrupt Excel-file!

This ist the simplified code snip:

```
OleContainer1->CreateObjectFromFile("input.xlsx", false);
OleContainer1->SaveAs("ouput.xlsx");
```

On the other hand: saving a docx file not ends in a corrupted file.

Please guide me!

Comment: It is quit interessting: I can open both Excel-Files with the 7zip "open archive" command. The Excel-file-structure in "output.xlsx" - file is within a "xl"-folder! How can I separat and save only this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
// You have to activate the object before accessing it
OleContainer1->DoVerb(ovShow);

Variant vOLEExcel = OleContainer1->OleObject.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

// Get document out of the OLE container
Variant vActiveDocument = vOLEExcel.OlePropertyGet("ActiveWorkBook");

// save it
vActiveDocument.Exec(Procedure("SaveAs") << L"C:\\temp\\output.xlsx");

// set saved-flag to inhibit save-questions
vActiveDocument.OlePropertySet("Saved", true);
```